# Selenium. Не могу кликнуть по элементам из списка

Tags: selenium, юнит-тесты, selenium-webdriver, python-3.6, chromedriver

Отобрал с помощью Selenium элементы в список:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="430de067e94c15423da45831fdeb1b4b", element="f5445e51-3cbe-4858-9916-6056b56e3a3d")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="430de067e94c15423da45831fdeb1b4b", element="3ae4a286-6748-4f74-8827-a0ac017b1423")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="430de067e94c15423da45831fdeb1b4b", element="a400be0d-b747-4cc4-804b-ba789edc80b6")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="430de067e94c15423da45831fdeb1b4b", element="b7b0910d-19f9-4c5b-8196-b927d0132166")>]
```

Но при попытке кликнуть на каждый из них через цикл:

```
for j in i:
    print(j)
    j.click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
..self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="В" title="ВВВ">...</div> is not clickable at point (508, 465). Other element would receive the click: <h3 class="ot-dpd-title">...</h3>
      (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)
```

Кто сталкивался с подобным? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить

Comment: либо элемент не загрузился, либо он не кликабелен. Можете показать на что вы пытаетесь кликнуть?

Comment: вы кликаете то ли в div, то ли в h3...

Comment: да, кликаю на div, так как ссылка скрыта, можно перейти только так. Проблема в том, что если не отбирать конкретные номера div, а взять список из всех подобных div, то click() срабатывает..

Comment: @Jack_oS я вот про это: i = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='S']")
                print(len(i))
                for j in i:
                    j.click()
                    time.sleep(2) из вот этого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1251484/362663

Comment: @ChikChirik так не на, что кликать же там, вы сайт скиньте тогда, чтобы потыкать